# Wifi and ethernet networking stopped working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, ethernet

I have a System76 Kudu Professional version kudp1, it came with ubuntu 13.10 but I upgraded it to 14.04. After the last upgrade I did it stopped detecting ethernet and wifi networks.

**nm-tool** output:

```
NetworkManager Tool
State: disconnected
```

**sudo lshw -C network** output:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
     description: Network controller
     product: Wireless 7260
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
     version: 73
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
     description: Ethernet controller
     product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0.2
     bus info: pci@0000:05:00.2
     version: 0a
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

**iwconfig** output:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**nmcli nm** output:

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         disconnected    enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that takes a look at this issue I have.

Comment: Thanks for your question! Let's grab a couple of pictures to better illustrate what the issue is. Go ahead and open your networks menu in the top-left corner of the screen, then press PrtSc on your keyboard. It's just to the left of the F12 key. That will grab a screenshot that I can use to better diagnose the issue. Make sure you have an Ethernet cable plugged in when you do this.